# Install procedure of Office/PowerPoint 2010 (VSTO) Add-In on target machines

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

I created an application-level Add-In for PowerPoint with VSTO and Visual Studio.
Some Information about configuration/versions:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2010
- At the beginning, I have chosen the predefined "PowerPoint 2010 Add-In" project type/template
- In the project properties, the target framework is set to ".NET Framework 4.0"

So far, so good.

My aim is to distribute this add-In to people that haven't installed the Visual Studio (and therefore are missing the VSTO libs etc.). It doesn't really need to be a highly comfortable and foolproof thing, just a fast way to install the Add-In and the dependencies on target machines.

What I found is [this link (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx). Is this still up to date for my intent or is there a faster way? I mean that article is quite a long one with potential for errors if you miss something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look in to [Clickonce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb821233%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for simple deployments. It is quite same for VS2010.